# "ValueError: Timezone offset does not match system offset: 28800 != 7200. Please, check your config files."

Tags: python, ubuntu, timezone, alibaba-cloud

I just got the error from the subject of this question, when running a python app on a cloud server (Alibaba Cloud). Any idea how to solve it on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ok, i found it:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure tzdata
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also set the timezone information for the specific user:
edit `.bashrc` to add a line like:

```sh
export TZ="/usr/share/zoneinfo/America/Chicago"
```

More details: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-linux-set-time-zone-per-user-basis/

Comment: This worked for me with: export TZ='/usr/share/zoneinfo/US/Eastern' !

Answer (score 0):

I once solved this problem in docker

```
ENV TZ=Asia/Shanghai
RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone
ENV LANG=en_US.UTF-8
ENV LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone
RUN ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Shanghai /etc/localtime
RUN echo 'Asia/Shanghai' >/etc/timezone
```